# how to check outh token is going to expire before 5 minute of DateTimeOffset.Now

Tags: c#

I have a token with `expires_in` and the value is 3600 in Seconds. How to check token is expires before 5 minute of DateTimeOffset.Now?

Here I am getting conversion error, `expiresInSeconds' is a string value.

```
 var expiresInSeconds = GetDictionaryKeyValue(tokenResponse, "expires_in");

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(expiresInSeconds)
                && expiresInSeconds < DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(ExpirationMarginInMinutes))
                {
                    return tokenResponse;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? It compares two DateTimeOffset values.  But without knowing more about what you're trying to do, this is only a guess.

```
&& DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(Int32.Parse(expiresInSeconds) 
    < DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(ExpirationMarginInMinutes))
```

Comment: it's giving me error `Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'DateTimeOffset'`

Comment: I am generating a token which expires in 3600 sec, how to know it's going to expires before 5 minute? this is my requirement.